# Flutter - How can I follow the uninstall of the application?

Tags: flutter, uninstallation

I am developing a flutter app. I want to update its status in my database when the user deletes the app from own phone. How can I follow these changes? Is it possible on flutter?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it in iOS, but for android, you can use [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) package to get the current list of installed apps and then compare it to the previously fetched data.

First, add this to your androids `manifest` file:

```
<manifest...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

</manifest>
```

and then use it:

```
List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do that, but @payam-asefi answer doesn't look right.

[device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) wouldn't help to detect it's own app deletion since flutter framework wouldn't even be running on on app deletion.

Here's two possible solutions.

1 - [Harder/complete one](https://medium.com/naukri-engineering/how-to-find-uninstall-users-on-android-and-ios-apps-cfa03952bdb5): This one offers full tracking of individual users/devices

2 -  The way I did in one of the apps I worked on (only works on android):

- Added Firebase to our Flutter app
- Added Firebase analytics

By default analytics already reports some events, including `app_remove` (android only)

- When the user logs in, set some key informations with `FirebaseAnalytics setUserProperty` method.

Example:

```
analytics.setUserProperty(name: 'id', value: user.id);
```

- Marked `app_remove` event as a conversion event (Yes I know this is a work around). This needs to be done since cloud functions is only triggered by conversion events.
- On the same Firebase project, created a cloud function that will be triggered by `app_remove` and will call an API endpoint to update the user status.

On the cloud function, you can check the event name and user property (assuming using JS) like this:

```
const eventName = event.eventDim[0].name;
const userId = event.userDim.userProperties.id;
```